# In postgres I see a table name which I didn't create at all

Tags: python, postgresql, django-models

The name is strange as well, below is how the table name got created
`<tablename like 'attribute value'>`  (I haven't given the original table name here, the whole string inside the angular bracket is the table name)
Eg: student like 'xxxx' (where xxx is a name of a student)

Its the last table that got created. Any idea on how this will happen

Comment: Mu guess: a mistyped command or code string in your application. Using protective quotes you can create an arbitrarily named table.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere your code (either in `python`/`django` or some table creation init script) is running something like:

```
  CREATE TABLE "<tablename like 'attribute value'>" (name text, salary numeric);
```

Of course if you were  mucking around in the shell this could have happened by accident.

Remove the table with:

```
 DROP TABLE "<tablename like 'attribute value'>";
```

Then be sure to:

- check your application for security issues (make sure a form isn't doing this !?)
- check your code for sanity (make sure any SQL that is being run is prepared properly)
- check your `psql` history to see if you accidentally ran such a command manually
- more ... suggestions to follow ;-)

Comment: Am not able to remove this table, since the name is strange and with keyword, its not letting me to do so.

Comment: You need to make sure the name you are passing to `DROP TABLE` is **exactly** the same as the name of the table and that you have escaped (quoted) the spaces and other odd syntax.

Comment: drop table student like 'xxx_yyy', how do I delete this table?
[student like 'xxx_yyy'] <--- this is the table name inside square brackets

Comment: `DROP TABLE "[student like 'xxx_yyy']" ;`  if it works vote the answer up :-)  Good luck.